# What is the logic behind recommended normalization parameters in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torchvision

On the PyTorch [documentation for torchvision.models](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html), it is states that images have to be loaded in a range of [0,1] and then normalized using `mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]` and `std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]`. What is the logic behind these specific values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58151507/674487) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57532661/674487), and also in the [pytorch discussion forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/normalization-in-the-mnist-example/457/7?u=kharshit)

As described in the links, these values were computed over the Imagenet training data. From the last link, which is the explanation by [Soumith Chintala](https://soumith.ch/):

> On Imagenet, we’ve done a pass on the dataset and calculated per-channel mean/std.